# xcode 6.1.1 Export as a Mac Installer Package app crashing

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, installation

I'm exporting my Mac OS X app outside the app store as a Mac Installer Package using Xcode 6.1.1 and Swift language. When I install the app and launch it, it crashes showing a code signing error, my target is OS X 10.10. I don't use sandbox, I have all the entitlements and a developer ID certificate even for the installer package distribution. The validation says that the archive is ok. If I export as a developer ID signed application the app works fine. Any ideas?

```
Process:               
Path:                  

Identifier:            
Version:               ???
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-01-22 09:37:13.177 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.1 (14B25)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        1B3648C4-3E46-7439-5276-1E15C8092855

Sleep/Wake UUID:       B9EC87D2-20A8-483F-9997-E41038707A08

Time Awake Since Boot: 18000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       2200 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

kernel messages:

VM Regions Near 0x7fff77c550a8 (cr2):
    __LINKEDIT             00007fff6d9a1000-00007fff6d9b5000 [   80K] r--/rwx SM=COW  /usr/lib/dyld
--> Submap                 00007fff70000000-00007fff80000000 [256.0M] r--/rwx SM=PRV  process-only VM submap
    unused shlib __DATA    00007fff77aa0000-00007fff7a030000 [ 37.6M] rw-/rw- SM=COW  system shared lib __DATA not used by this process

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   dyld                            0x00007fff6d932000 _dyld_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x000000000000000d  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x0000000000000000  rsp: 0x00007fff56bc3a70
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000000
  r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x00007fff6d932000  rfl: 0x0000000000000201  cr2: 0x00007fff77c550a8

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x020000f4
Trap Number:     133
```

Comment: What's the error you get? Please add this error-message to your question.

Comment: what error message is Mac OS X sending, show your logs, or start your app on command line.

Comment: I am having a similar issue. I got this from the console: `because its use of the com.apple.developer.team-identifier entitlement is not allowed (error code -67050)`. My app use MapKit and has an extension. The archive validation says everything is okay.

Comment: i'm having this issue too... Does anyone solve this? i'm getting crazy...

Comment: Do you have the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: download Xcode auxiliary tools from October 2013 and `use PackageMaker.app`, it's straightforward to use and it makes the package installer without any crash. Tested on 2 Macs.

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, I figured out that this doesn't seem to affect app review. Once your archive is validated, you can just submit your app and it should work fine when downloaded from the app store.